# Populate wordpress post form fields by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a wordpress custom post "movies" in which I have taxonomies like actor, director

I also have custom field which holds imdb url of a movie, now what I was trying to do is fetch movie details from that imdb url by ajax.

I am getting movie details like, title, description, actors, directors, movie poster url (script saves movie poster inside temp directory when you fetch imdb data of a movie) in ajax return data, but I want to populate wordpress post title, description, custom taxonomies (actor, director) and movie poster as featured image so user will just need to save post.

But I don't know how to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Without you showing some code, it's all an imagination exercise. How is this happenning: Custom Field -> Fetch Data?

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by brasofilo some code would help (...get a decent response). but a quick thought...if you know the id's of each field in dom, and know the index/key that corresponds to it in your returned ajax object, then do (jquery for simplicity) 
`$('#field-id input).attr('value', 'someval');` or similar on each field. surely there is some sort of mapping between fields and taxomonies etc.